# Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jhipster, spring-boot-test

Hoping are well.

I'm not using web.xml for my spring configuration, and when running my repository tests after migrating to JHipster I'm getting this error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in
> class path resource
> [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method
> 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer@7744f9fa
> to already built object

Is there any recommendation?

Comment: What do you mean by "migrating to JHipster"?

Comment: Please share your security configuration.